# Calculate sum and min max across each group in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have a below sample data frame

```
df <- data.frame("Group"= c(1,1,2,2,2),"H" = 
c("H1","H3","H3","H4","H2"), "W1" = c(95, 0, 0,0,50) , "W2" = c(0, 
95,95, 0,85),"W3" = c(85, 50,50 ,95,0))
```

Need to calculate two additional Metrics:
1st Metric : Based on each group and rows across w1,w2,w3 of that group if the value is equal or more than 85 for w1, w2 & w3 then output is 100%.
For Example: For Group 2, For w2 & w3, Maximum value is equal more than 85
and For w1 , it is less than 85 so result is **66.7**

2nd Metric : Minimum of maximum of rows across w1,w2,w3 columns of that group. For Example : For Group 2, min(max[0 0 50], max[95 0 85], max[50 95 0]) = **50**

For more clarity, Here is desired output data frame:

```
DesiredDf <- data.frame("Group"= c(1,1,2,2,2),"H" =     
c("H1","H3","H3","H4","H2"), "W1" = c(95, 0, 0,0,50) , 
"W2" = c(0, 95,95, 0,85), "W3" = c(85, 50,50 ,95,0),
"W" = c(100,100,66.7 ,66.7,66.7),MINMAX = c(85,85,50,50,50))
```

Have tried out for loop and sapply method but the actual data set is too large and execution is too slow.Looking for ways to calculate these metrics more seamlessly in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(w = rowMeans(cbind(max(W1) >= 85, max(W2) >= 85, max(W3) >= 85)),
         minmax = min(max(W1), max(W2), max(W3)))

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group H        W1    W2    W3     w minmax
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1    1. H1      95.    0.   85. 1.00     85.
2    1. H3       0.   95.   50. 1.00     85.
3    2. H3       0.   95.   50. 0.667    50.
4    2. H4       0.    0.   95. 0.667    50.
5    2. H2      50.   85.    0. 0.667    50.
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting dplyr solution. If number of W1,W2 .... columns varies based on data frame generated i.e. It can be W1 and W2 only or W1, W2, and W3 or W1,W2,W3, W4 and W5 then what could be the optimized way to modify the above solution. Currently I am using conditional statement but looking for better way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

The data.table way:

```
# use data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# aggregate data by group in order to calculate the 2 desired metrics
df1 <- df[ , .(maxw1 = max(W1), maxw2 = max(W2), maxw3 = max(W3)), by=Group]

# calculate the metrics
df1[ , metric1 := rowMeans(cbind(maxw1>=85, maxw2>=85, maxw3>=85))]
df1[ , metric2 := do.call(pmin,.SD), .SDcols = c("maxw1", "maxw2", "maxw3")]

# merge metrics back on to original dataframe
df <- merge(df, df1[ , .(Group, metric1, metric2)], by="Group")
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting data.table solution. If number W1, W2 ..... column varies in the data frame, what could be the best way to fit this scenario also in above solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "varies".  Do you mean you have one dataframe with W1-W3 and another with W1-W5, or do you mean W1 is named Wone in the second dataframe?  If you only have a few dataframes, your fastest and easiest approach is probably to just handle each one manually using similar, but modified, code as in my example above.  However, if you have tens or hundreds of dataframes, each with a W1-Wx where x can be any number, then it's probably best to post a new question on SO to see if the community has a more general approach.

Comment: Does pmin work in data.table? It gives different result when I try min and pmin @DanY

Comment: @D.Shin - `min()` finds the minimum of its input, so it returns a scalar value (one number).  `pmin()` stands for parallel minimum and returns a vector of values.  For example, suppose `X <- cbind( c(3,2), c(1,5) )`.  Then `min(X)` = 1 while `pmin(X)` = [1, 2]